# SQL Query for finding longest streak of wins

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have data like below -

```
Year,winning_country
2001,IND
2002,IND
2003,IND
2004,AUS
2005,AUS
2006,SA
2007,SA
2008,SA
2009,IND
2010,IND
2011,IND
2012,IND
2013,AUS
2014,AUS
2015,SA
2016,NZ
2017,SL
2018,IND
```

The question here is to find out the longest streak of wins for each country and desired output will be like below -

```
Country,no_of_wins
IND,4
AUS,2
SA,3
SL,1
NZ,1
```

Can someone help here.

Comment: Can I have redshift SQL query for the same.

Comment: what sql do you have so far? what is your result so far? (this is not a service to write sql for you)

Answer (score 4):

This is a gaps and islands problem, but the simplest method is to subtract a sequence from the year.  So, to get all the sequences:

```
select country, count(*) as streak,
       min(year) as from_year, max(year) as to_year
from (select year, country,
             row_number() over (partition by country order by year) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by country, (year - seqnum);
```

To get the longest per country, aggregate again or use window functions:

```
select country, streak
from (select country, count(*) as streak,
             min(year) as from_year, max(year) as to_year,
             row_number() over (partition by country order by count(*) desc) as seqnum_2
      from (select year, country,
                   row_number() over (partition by country order by year) as seqnum
            from t
           ) t
      group by country, (year - seqnum)
     ) cy
where seqnum_2 = 1;
```

I prefer using `row_number()` to get the longest streak because it allows you to also get the years when it occurred.

Comment: How would you go about finding a country's current win streak? (e.g. 1 for IND)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like an gaps-and-islands problem.

The SQL below calculates some ranking based on 2 [row_number](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_ROW_NUMBER.html).

Then it's just a matter of grouping.

```
SELECT q2.Country, MAX(q2.no_of_wins) AS no_of_wins
FROM
(
  SELECT q1.winning_country as Country, 
  COUNT(*) AS no_of_wins
  FROM
  (
    SELECT t.Year, t.winning_country,
     (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.Year ASC) -
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.winning_country ORDER BY t.Year)) AS rnk
    FROM yourtable t
  ) q1
  GROUP BY q1.winning_country, q1.rnk
) q2
GROUP BY q2.Country
ORDER BY MAX(q2.no_of_wins) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If Redshift supports analytic function, below would be the query.

```
with t1 as 
(
select 2001 as year,'IND' as cntry from dual union
select 2002,'IND' from dual union
select 2003,'IND' from dual union
select 2004,'AUS' from dual union
select 2005,'AUS' from dual union
select 2006,'SA' from dual union
select 2007,'SA' from dual union
select 2008,'SA' from dual union
select 2009,'IND' from dual union
select 2010,'IND' from dual union
select 2011,'IND' from dual union
select 2012,'IND' from dual union
select 2013,'AUS' from dual union
select 2014,'AUS' from dual union
select 2015,'SA' from dual union
select 2016,'NZ' from dual union
select 2017,'SL' from dual union
select 2018,'IND' from dual) ,
t2 as (select year, cntry, year - row_number() over (partition by cntry order by year) as grpBy from t1 order by cntry),
t3 as (select cntry, count(grpBy) as consWins from t2 group by cntry, grpBy),
res as (select cntry, consWins, row_number() over (partition by cntry order by consWins desc) as rnk from t3)
select cntry, consWins from res where rnk=1;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: what is "dual" in your sql above?

Comment: dual is dummy table in oracle, i wanted to test my query so create d a temp table using CTE and dual in my local

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that leverages the use of Redshift Python UDF's

There may be simpler ways to achieve the same but this is a good example of how to create a simple UDF.

```
create table temp_c (competition_year int ,winning_country varchar(4));
insert into temp_c (competition_year, winning_country)
values
(2001,'IND'),
(2002,'IND'),
(2003,'IND'),
(2004,'AUS'),
(2005,'AUS'),
(2006,'SA'),
(2007,'SA'),
(2008,'SA'),
(2009,'IND'),
(2010,'IND'),
(2011,'IND'),
(2012,'IND'),
(2013,'AUS'),
(2014,'AUS'),
(2015,'SA'),
(2016,'NZ'),
(2017,'SL'),
(2018,'IND')
;

create or replace function find_longest_streak(InputStr varChar)
  returns integer
stable
as $$
    MaxStreak=0
    ThisStreak=0
    ThisYearStr=''
    LastYear=0
    for ThisYearStr in InputStr.split(','):
        if int(ThisYearStr) == LastYear + 1:
            ThisStreak+=1
        else:
            if ThisStreak > MaxStreak:
                MaxStreak=ThisStreak
            ThisStreak=1
        LastYear=int(ThisYearStr)
    return max(MaxStreak,1)
$$ language plpythonu;

select winning_country,
       find_longest_streak(listagg(competition_year,',') within group (order by competition_year))
from temp_c
group by winning_country
order by 2 desc
;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like...

```
SELECT
   winning_country,
   COUNT(*)
GROUP BY winning_country
HAVING MAX(year) - MIN(year) = COUNT(year) - 1
```

This assumes no duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a session abstraction do the trick:

```
WITH winning_changes AS (
  SELECT *,
         CASE WHEN LAG(winning_country) OVER (ORDER BY year) <> winning_country THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS same_winner
  FROM winners
),

sequences AS (
  SELECT *,
         SUM(same_winner) OVER (ORDER BY year) AS winning_session
  FROM winning_changes
),

streaks AS (
  SELECT winning_country AS country,
         winning_session,
         COUNT(*) streak
  FROM sequences
  GROUP BY 1,2
)

SELECT country,
       MAX(streak) AS no_of_wins
FROM streaks
GROUP BY 1;
```